# Disable home key button android 1.6?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I want to disable home key. I tried this code this will work on android 2.1 above but I want it for android 1.6

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The only option you have is to to let your app acts as an homescreen so the button will have no effect. To do this let your activity be launched via intent ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME, as describted in the [intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

}